# Как сделать сайт без горизонтальной прокрутки?

Tags: html, css

Существует ли универсальный метод?

Comment: А "резиновый" сайт уже не выполняет этих функций?

Comment: lol
    
    width: 620px; margin: 0px auto;

Answer (score 2):

```
html,body{
max-width:100%;
}
```

не за что

Comment: наверное, еще надо  overflow:hidden; на всякий случай

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body{overflow-x:hidden}
```

Comment: Да ты суров и жесток =)